# Jetpack Compose model list becomes jumbled when adding new items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an issue with Jetpack compose displaying a model containing a `ModelList` of items. When new items are added, the order of the UI elements becomes incorrect.

Here's a very simple `CounterModel` containing a `ModelList` of `ItemModel`s:

```kotlin
@Model
data class CounterModel(
    var counter: Int = 0,
    var name: String = "",
    val items: ModelList<ItemModel> = ModelList()
)

@Model
data class ItemModel(
    var name: String
)
```

The screen shows two card rows for each `ItemModel`: `RowA` and `RowB`.
When I create this screen initialised with the following `CounterModel`:

```kotlin
val model = CounterModel()
model.name="hi"
model.items.add(ItemModel("Item 1"))
model.items.add(ItemModel("Item 2"))
CounterModelScreen(model)
```

...it displays as expected like this:

Item 1
Row A

Item 1
Row B

Item 2
Row A

Item 2
Row B

When I click my 'add' button, to insert a new `ItemModel`, I simply expect to see

Item 3
Row A

Item 3
Row B

At the bottom. But instead, the order is jumbled, and I see two rowAs then two rowBs:

Item 1
Row A

Item 1
Row B

Item 2
Row A

Item 3
Row A

Item 3
Row B

Item 2
Row B

I don't really understand how this is possible. The UI code is extremely simple: loop through the `items` and emit `RowA` and `RowB` for each one:

```kotlin
for (i in counterModel.items.indices) {
    RowA(counterModel, i)
    RowB(counterModel, i)
}
```

Using Android Studio 4.0C6

Here's the complete code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CounterModelScreen(counterModel: CounterModel) {
    Column {
        TopAppBar(title = {
            Text(
                text = "Counter Model"
            )
        })

        CounterHeader(counterModel)
        for (i in counterModel.items.indices) {
            RowA(counterModel, i)
            RowB(counterModel, i)
        }
        Button(
            text = "Add",
            onClick = {
                counterModel.items.add(ItemModel("Item " + (counterModel.items.size + 1)))
            })
    }
}

@Composable
fun CounterHeader(counterModel: CounterModel) {
    Text(text = counterModel.name)
}

@Composable
fun RowA(counterModel: CounterModel, index: Int) {
    Padding(padding = 8.dp) {
        Card(color = Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)) {
            Column(crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand) {
                Text(
                    text = counterModel.items[index].name
                )
                Text(text = "Row A")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowB(counterModel: CounterModel, index: Int) {
    Padding(padding = 8.dp) {
        Card(color = Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)) {
            Column(crossAxisSize = LayoutSize.Expand) {
                Text(
                    text = counterModel.items[index].name
                )
                Text(text = "Row B")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that removing the `CounterHeader(counterModel)` call just above the for loop fixed the problem, but that just makes me even more confused. The `CounterHeader` fun is simply `Text(text = counterModel.name)`, why should that affect anything? It even works if I _inline_ the `Text` (ie remove the fun).

Comment: Still occurs in Android Studio 4.0C7

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it using **compose-1.0.0-alpha07** and making some changes to adapt the code to the changed APIs. Everything works flawlessly so my guess is that something was broken in an older version of compose as the code looks correct and works in more recent versions with the mentioned changes.

I have also modified your code to use states as recommended in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) and added a ViewModel that will help you decouple the Views from the data management:

ViewModel

```
class CounterModelViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val myBaseModel = CounterModel().apply {
        name = "hi"
        items.add(ItemModel("Item 1"))
        items.add(ItemModel("Item 2"))
    }

    private val _modelLiveData = MutableLiveData(myBaseModel)
    val modelLiveData: LiveData<CounterModel> = _modelLiveData

    fun addNewItem() {
        val oldCounterModel = modelLiveData.value ?: CounterModel()
        // Items is casted to a new MutableList because the new state won't be notified if the new
        // counter model content is the same one as the old one. You can also change any other
        // properties instead like the name or the counter
        val newItemsList = oldCounterModel.items.toMutableList()
        newItemsList.add(ItemModel("Item " + (newItemsList.size + 1)))
        
        // Pass a new instance of CounterModel to the LiveData
        val newCounterModel = oldCounterModel.copy(items = newItemsList)
        _modelLiveData.value = newCounterModel
    }
}
```

Composable Views updated:

```
@Composable
fun CounterModelScreen(counterModel: CounterModel, onAddNewItem: () -> Unit) {
    ScrollableColumn {
        TopAppBar(title = {
            Text(
                text = "Counter Model"
            )
        })

        CounterHeader(counterModel)
        counterModel.items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            RowA(counterModel, index)
            RowB(counterModel, index)
        }
        Button(
            onClick = onAddNewItem
        ) {
            Text(text = "Add")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CounterHeader(counterModel: CounterModel) {
    Text(text = counterModel.name)
}

@Composable
fun RowA(counterModel: CounterModel, index: Int) {

    Card(
        backgroundColor = Color.White,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text(
                text = counterModel.items[index].name
            )
            Text(text = "Row A")
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun RowB(counterModel: CounterModel, index: Int) {

    Card(
        backgroundColor = Color.Gray,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text(
                text = counterModel.items[index].name
            )
            Text(text = "Row B")
        }
    }

}
```

This previous code is called from another composable function that contains the instance of the ViewModel, however you can change this to an activity or a fragment with an instance of the mentioned ViewModel, it's up to your preference.

```
@Composable
fun MyCustomScreen(viewModel: CounterModelViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val modelState: CounterModel by viewModel.modelLiveData.observeAsState(CounterModel())

    CounterModelScreen(
        counterModel = modelState,
        onAddNewItem = {
            viewModel.addNewItem()
        }
    )
}
```